# Get BIOS/Firmware version of SoftLayer bare metal device

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Trying to get the following data type for our deployed bare metal devices, so that we can see what BIOS/firmware version is running on them:

SoftLayer_Hardware_Component_Firmware

But I can't seem to find any method, or relational property that actually returns this object.

Tried dumping all childComponents of a SoftLayer_Hardware_Server, but it wasn't there, not under "motherboard" either.

Beginning to run out of ideas... Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API does not return that information.

Comment: So they just create a data type in the API that gives me exactly what I need, without giving us any way to actually get that data? Doesn't make any sense.. :/

Comment: you can get that datatype https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Hardware/$BAREMETALID/getObject?objectMask=mask[activeComponents[hardwareComponentModel[firmwares]]]    however I do not think it contains the data that you want

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Weird that they can pull firmware info from the RAID cards, and other hardware adapters, but not the motherboard. Thanks anyway! :)